# Functions on Finitely-Generated, Nilpotent Free, k-Algebras Determined by Values on Closed Points

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am working (slowly and with much labor) through Vakil's Algebraic Geometry and came upon this problem.

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and $A = k[x_1,... ,x_n]/I$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra with $\mathfrak{N}(A) = {0}$ (so the discussion of §3.2.13 applies). Consider the set $X = SpecA$ as a subset of $\mathbb{A}_n^k$. Show that functions on $X$ are determined by their values on the closed points (by the weak Nullstellensatz 3.2.4, the “classical” points $k^n$. The space $\mathbb{A}_n^k \cap SpecA$ of $Spec A$). Hint: if $f$ and $g$ are different functions on $X$, then $f − g$ is nowhere zero on an open subset of $X$. Use Exercise 3.6.J(a).

The reference exercise 3.6.J(a) shows that for a field $k$ and a finitely-generated $k$-algebra $A$, the set of closed points in $SpecA$ (previously established as corresponding to maximal ideals of $A$) is dense in $SpecA$.

Okay I stumbled through exercise 3.6.J(a) on my own, and I think I see where the starting line is for this race. I imagine that I should look at $f(\mathfrak{m}) - g(\mathfrak{m})$ for every $\mathfrak{m}$. If $f$ and $g$ are equal at every point $\mathfrak{m}$, then $f(\mathfrak{m}) - g(\mathfrak{m}) = 0$ for every $\mathfrak{m}$ so that $f-g$ has a zero on every open subset of $X$ (using the fact that the set of closed points is dense in $X$) and therefore $f = g$. But why is the comment about $f-g$ being nowhere zero on an open subset of $X$ true?

Moreover, given the (not entirely rigorous) proof above, wouldn't the comment in question imply that $f = g$ even if $f-g=0$ on just one open subset of $X$?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer. I imagine I might be asking a trivial question and just forgetting some topology basics or some fact about $SpecA$. (Anyway it's good to practice some LaTeX ;)

Comment: It's a little hard to tease out the question but here are some remarks: (1) I don't see the need to embed in $\mathbb A^n$. (2) I think the main ingredient you are missing is that the set of $x \in X$ where $f$ and $g$ "agree" is closed. I think he has an exercise somewhere earlier like "on a locally ringed space the points where a global function vanishes form a closed set".

Comment: (3) For the same reason, if $f$ and $g$ take on the same values on a dense subset then they do so everywhere. Note that if the ring is not reduced then this is not the same as them actually being the same thing.

Comment: Actually, the only thing I don't see here is you using the reducedness. So be sure to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Observe that the open set $D(f-g)$ contains no closed points. It is therefore an open set disjoint from a dense set. What does this imply about $D(f-g)$? What does that implication tell you about $f-g$?

Comment: I think I'm following you (now as opposed to when I first looked at your answer at 11:30 last night haha). Because $D(f-g)$ contains no closed points, it must be empty. Hence $V(f-g)$ is the entire space Spec$A$, meaning that $f-g \in \mathfrak{N}(A)$ and must be equal to $0$ with the condition that $A$ is nilpotent-free. (If $A$ were not nilpotent-free, then it would be possible that $(f-g)^n = 0$ instead of $f-g = 0$. Is that what you were meaning?

Comment: @TannerStrunk Yup, that's exactly right, glad to be a help!